# What happens between the time docker has pulled the image and the container is running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I'd like to know if there is additional extraction/caching going on on the disk after the image is pulled and before a service is started to run inside a container?

The reason for the ask is: the instance startup time in a warm pool. It looks like if a container is `run` and then shutdown the next startup is much faster than when the image is just pulled to disk.

Of course here the application itself could be doing additional file creation or downloading so that it runs faster the next time. Let's ignore that.